# Deploying a model calculated on PC to a linux server

Tags: r, linux

I'm using intensively R on my PC. I'm working on an easy document classification project and I got my `ctree` model working fine. Training set, validation set and the like. The results are promising.

Now I want to deploy my model for classification of incoming documents and I'm stuck. The path from moving my model produced on my PC to a linux server is a dark spot for me. I'm trying to figure how to export my model and place it into the server working flow. Is capable R of managing files?

It's a requirement that the program renames the file after predicting the class adding a tag. If the file can not be renamed, a csv file saving the result (new file - predicted class) would be acceptable.

Do I need to use Bash? R script? Python?

Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume this server you're working on has a working R installation; i'm not an RSTUDIO user, but if there's a way to get a plain text file of the R code that runs your model, that's what you need.  Investigate trying to write a bash script that accepts a filename as an argument and calls the R interpreter with your script and the filename.  If you need to automate this, you could create a service.  That'd be advanced.

Comment: The general idea would be save the output of your model using `save(your_model)`. See docs here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html. Then put the saved model in your path on Linux and load it in an R Script on the server using `load(your_model)`

Comment: Thanks! i will read the documentation you refer.

Comment: So, If I understood you correctly @justin , a new file arrives and a bash script calls an R script passing the file as an argument and the R script returns the class predicted for this document, correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.  The part I can't really speak to is how to have that happen "automatically".. a bash script that calls R on a file should be straightforward though.